# Invalid SharePoint Online list 'Documents' (ErrorCode: 0x0201000D) with Migration Tool csv

Tags: sharepoint-online

When using Sharepoint Migration Tool on a language other than English to copy files to the default "Shared Documents" (or "Documents" as you are to use), it gives  Invalid SharePoint Online list 'Documents' (ErrorCode: 0x0201000D). 
Whats the correct Document Library name to use?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a Language issue. Make sure that the language settings of the user used in SharePoint is set to the same language as the original site creation default language.

Or use the same language that SharePoint Migration Tool used for library name.

Comment: SharePoint Migration Tool is only in English. However, when selecting "File Share" rather than CSV, it correctly discovers the Library name, (In my case, in Japanese). All Other libraries created in another Language are created as "DocLibx". This issue is only for the default "Documents"  Library. MS Details seems wrong.